# Draw ellipse like line in Affinity

Tags: vector, affinity-designer

I'm rather new to vector graphics and trying to learn Affinity Designer.
Could someone give an example how to draw a line like the example attached?

[image]

I'm really curious how to get the curviness but still have the sharp corners.

Regards,

Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points with the pen tool. Select the Pen Tool. Click and drag along the tangent of your curve by approximately 1/3 the distance of the entire curve. And click the other end of the curve and drag it out. You can then hold Command down to go back and adjust any of the anchor points.

[image]

Note I don't have Affinity Designer anymore so I'm doing this in Affinity Photo but it should be exactly the same in Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create a simple (open) curve with the Pen tool. Just two nodes. Play with the handles til the curve fits your needs. Give the curve no fill color - only a contour color.

Then comes the trick: In the contour tab use the **"Pressure"** ("Druck" in the German UI) curve to start your contour stroke small, then make the contour fat and towards the end small again. You can save pressure presets with your drawing.

See attached screenshot.
[image: Controur with Stroke Pressure]